# <kbd>CTRL</kbd> is rendered in multiple lines with Google Chrome 21/22

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, kbd

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>  looks weird as the chars don't fit the 26px width of the key, making it a multiline.

Making it one pixel wider, resolves it on my machine. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> fits nicely.

Comment: I see the broken `<kbd>CTRL</kbd>` on Chrome 21 on Windows too. I can also reproduce the problem with `<kbd>WWW</kbd>`.

Comment: Looks fine in Firefox 14.0.1 on Linux.

Comment: Hmm, was hoping this issue wouldn't hit Chrome stable, but I guess it did. Adding `white-space: nowrap;` fixes the problem, although that could cause some other issues if people wanted to abuse the `<kbd>` tag. In this particular case, having the font at anything other than 11 px also makes Chrome size the container correctly.

Comment: Chrome22 on Windows.

Comment: No repro on Chrome 20/Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to repro this in Chrome 21.0.1180.57 OSX. I added white-space: nowrap as Tim suggested and verified that it doesn't mess up other browsers. The change will be in the next prod build.